# Magento 2.1.9 : unable to access to storage root in wysiwug popup

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.9

**Preconditions**

```
Magento 2.1.9
Add image to block from admin
```

**Steps to reproduce**

```
Add image to block by wysiwyg files
```

**Expected result**

```
Wysiwyg popup with storage root and all files
```

**Actual result**

```
Wysiwyg popup = blank page
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Can you please help me to find a solution for this issue, I thing there is a problem with treeJson ajax.